# How to fetch a backbone collection without encoding the URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, urlencode, github-api

We need to send request

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=angular+user:angular&order=desc
```

but in console request is

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=angular%2Buser%3Aangular&order=desc
```

The collection

```
var RepoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',

    initialize: function () {},

    fetch: function(options) {
        var params = {
            q:"angular+user:angular",
            order:"desc"
        };
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, {
            data: $.param(params) 
        });
    }
});
```

For example:

Request: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=com%2Buser%3Attomashuk&order=desc

```
{
  "total_count": 0,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [

  ]
}
```

Request: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=com+user:ttomashuk&order=desc

```
{
      "total_count": 1,
      "incomplete_results": false,
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 104921385,
          "name": "CompanyOrganizer",
          "full_name": "ttomashuk/CompanyOrganizer",
          .........
          "score": 1.2680688
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. But both URLs are the same. In the second case, it is just using the standard url encoding. URL encoding for `+` is `%2B` and `:` is `%3A`.

Comment: Poonacha is right, what's the error or the problem you're facing? It looks like you have a problem where you think the URL encoding is the source, but it's probably not.

Comment: I have got different results for both requests. For example: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=com+user:ttomashuk&order=desc   {
  "total_count": 1,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [ ...... ]}  and https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=com%2Buser%3Attomashuk&order=desc  {
  "total_count": 0,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [

  ]
}

Comment: Good point, please edit this additional information into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jQuery documentation on `$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) shows exactly what you're looking for:

```js
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  },
  b: [1, 2, 3]
};
var recursiveEncoded = $.param(myObject);
var recursiveDecoded = decodeURIComponent($.param(myObject));

console.log("encoded:", recursiveEncoded);
console.log("decoded:", recursiveDecoded);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Which should output:

```
encoded: a%5Bone%5D=1&a%5Btwo%5D=2&a%5Bthree%5D=3&b%5B%5D=1&b%5B%5D=2&b%5B%5D=3
decoded: a[one]=1&a[two]=2&a[three]=3&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3
```

So you could fetch with:

```
return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, {
    data: decodeURIComponent($.param(params))
});
```

---

You should also pass any other *options* initially passed to fetch down to the original fetch call so your overriding is transparent:

```
fetch: function(options) {
    options = options || {};

    // extend the passed data with the default
    options.data = decodeURIComponent($.param(_.extend({
        q: "angular+user:angular",
        order: "desc"
    }, options.data)));

    return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```